# Capybara returning session data for the body when I stub application controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, stub

I have

```
allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
```

But for some reason when I print `page.body` I am getting

```
"Rack session data \"session_id\" : \"{session_id}\" \"user_id\" : 1 \"uid\" : \"{user uid}\"
```

Instead of HTML for a page. I'm very confused by this behavior. I'm on capybara 2.4.4

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.. How is `.current_user` related to `page.body`

Comment: It's on a page that requires login

Comment: please provide your entire spec code so we can better help you. And also your method in your ApplicationController methods you're testing

Comment: Lindsey, Not sure, if I understand your question. Can you please share the code, showing what you are trying to achieve and how you are opening the page?

Answer (score 0):

Did you visit the correct page?
The command for visiting a given page is `visit <insert path here>`. Make sure you visit your desired page before trying to retrieve its body.

Comment: I did provide that. So when the user isn't logged in it is correctly redirecting to the login page as it should.